# Woocommerce Recent Product Images Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, twig, timber

I'm trying to display the featured image from the product using:

```
{% filter shortcodes %}
    [recent_products per_page="12" columns="4"]
{% endfilter %}
```

Would I need to create a custom query to reference the images to be brought back?

If so could you please point me in the right direction.

Thanks Jake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Currently not possible with just the shortcode, you have to use the widget.